# ¿Por qué no entra en el bloque try-catch?

Tags: c#, .net

Estoy intentando debuggear el código de una aplicación. Pero me ocurre que ni siquiera entra en el siguiente bloque try-catch:

```
int enviarFonts = 0;
                int.TryParse(Convert.ToString(drConfiguracion["EnviarFonts"]), out enviarFonts);
                if (enviarFonts == 1)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //Parece que por aquí se envían las fonts. Vamos a quitar el if a ver que pasa.
                        if (oBalanza.aLista_Registro_Fonts == null)
                        {
                            DataTable dtFontsAsociadosModificados = AccesoDatosGenerico.EjecutaQuery(ConfiguracionApp.CONEXION_UPICKER, "SELECT * FROM dat_balanza WHERE IdBalanza=" + oBalanza.IdBalanzaMaestra + " AND IdTienda=" + oBalanza.IdTienda + " AND Modificado_Fonts=1 AND IdConfiguracion=" + oBalanza.IdConfiguracion + " AND IdEmpresa=" + oBalanza.IdEmpresa).Tables[0];
                            if (dtFontsAsociadosModificados.Rows.Count > 0)
                                oBalanza.Lista_Registro_Fonts = (Registros.GenerarRegistrosFonts_EnBytes(ref oBalanza, true, 0, oConexion, log));
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
                    }
```

Me extraña bastante, ya que el resto de comprobaciones son prácticamente identicas, y puedo entrar dentro de los bloques try-catch. ¿Por qué no me deja entrar en este caso en concreto? El problema es que al no entrar, no se envían las fonts. Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: No será `enviarFonts` distinto de 1?

Comment: Pon un punto de ruptura en la línea `if (enviarFonts == 1)`, comprueba el valor de `enviarFonts`. Tienes la opción de ejecutar paso-a-paso y ver qué camino sigue el programa.

Comment: Hay problemas con la función Convert. Parece que no funciona correctamente y no cambia el valor. Gracias por vuestros aportes y ayuda

Comment: Que devuelve drConfiguracion["EnviarFonts"] y porque tiene que cambiarlo a String?

Comment: Hola Duston. drConfiguracion es un objeto DataRow (de ahí las iniciales dr), y necesito convertirlo a String por compatibilidad de datos. Un saludo